# Implementing pagination in mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, pagination, mongodb-query

I know that it is a bad practice to use `skip` in order to implement pagination, because when your data gets large `skip` starts to consume a lot of memory. One way to overcome this trouble is to use natural order by `_id` field:

```
//Page 1
db.users.find().limit(pageSize);
//Find the id of the last document in this page
last_id = ...

//Page 2
users = db.users.find({'_id'> last_id}). limit(10);
```

The problem is - I'm new to mongo and do not know what is the best way to get this very `last_id`

Comment: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gt/

Comment: Thanks! But I can't see how should I get last_id. What code should I use instead of those dots: `last_id = ...`?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The concept you are talking about can be called "forward paging". A good reason for that is unlike using `.skip()` and `.limit()` modifiers this cannot be used to "go back" to a previous page or indeed "skip" to a specific page. At least not with a great deal of effort to store "seen" or "discovered" pages, so if that type of "links to page" paging is what you want, then you are best off sticking with the `.skip()` and `.limit()` approach, despite the performance drawbacks.

If it is a viable option to you to only "move forward", then here is the basic concept:

```js
db.junk.find().limit(3)

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c03f0c2f63310180151877"), "a" : 1, "b" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c03f0c2f63310180151878"), "a" : 4, "b" : 4 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c03f0c2f63310180151879"), "a" : 10, "b" : 10 }
```

Of course that's your first page with a limit of 3 items. Consider that now with code iterating the cursor:

```js
var lastSeen = null;
var cursor = db.junk.find().limit(3);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   var doc = cursor.next();
   printjson(doc);
   if (!cursor.hasNext())
     lastSeen = doc._id;
}
```

So that iterates the cursor and does something, and when it is true that the last item in the cursor is reached you store the `lastSeen` value to the present `_id`:

```js
ObjectId("54c03f0c2f63310180151879")
```

In your subsequent iterations you just feed that `_id` value which you keep ( in session or whatever ) to the query:

```js
var cursor = db.junk.find({ "_id": { "$gt": lastSeen } }).limit(3);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   var doc = cursor.next();
   printjson(doc);
   if (!cursor.hasNext())
     lastSeen = doc._id;
}

{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c03f0c2f6331018015187a"), "a" : 1, "b" : 1 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c03f0c2f6331018015187b"), "a" : 6, "b" : 6 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c03f0c2f6331018015187c"), "a" : 7, "b" : 7 }
```

And the process repeats over and over until no more results can be obtained.

That's the basic process for a natural order such as `_id`. For something else it gets a bit more complex. Consider the following:

```js
{ "_id": 4, "rank": 3 }
{ "_id": 8, "rank": 3 }
{ "_id": 1, "rank": 3 }    
{ "_id": 3, "rank": 2 }
```

To split that into two pages sorted by rank then what you essentially need to know is what you have "already seen" and exclude those results. So looking at a first page:

```js
var lastSeen = null;
var seenIds = [];
var cursor = db.junk.find().sort({ "rank": -1 }).limit(2);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   var doc = cursor.next();
   printjson(doc);
   if ( lastSeen != null && doc.rank != lastSeen )
       seenIds = [];
   seenIds.push(doc._id);
   if (!cursor.hasNext() || lastSeen == null)
     lastSeen = doc.rank;
}

{ "_id": 4, "rank": 3 }
{ "_id": 8, "rank": 3 }
```

On the next iteration you want to be less or equal to the lastSeen "rank" score, but also excluding those already seen documents. You do this with the [**`$nin`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/nin/) operator:

```js
var cursor = db.junk.find(
    { "_id": { "$nin": seenIds }, "rank": "$lte": lastSeen }
).sort({ "rank": -1 }).limit(2);

while (cursor.hasNext()) {
   var doc = cursor.next();
   printjson(doc);
   if ( lastSeen != null && doc.rank != lastSeen )
       seenIds = [];
   seenIds.push(doc._id);
   if (!cursor.hasNext() || lastSeen == null)
     lastSeen = doc.rank;
}

{ "_id": 1, "rank": 3 }    
{ "_id": 3, "rank": 2 }
```

How many "seenIds" you actually hold on to depends on how "granular" your results are where that value is likely to change. In this case you can check if the current "rank" score is not equal to the `lastSeen` value and discard the present `seenIds` content so it does not grow to much.

That's the basic concepts of "forward paging" for you to practice and learn.

Comment: @Neil-Lunn, such a full and nice explanation. I discovered something about you, It seems that you never sleep, I monitored you (kidding) and saw you are always online 24/7 ;)

Comment: @Disposer Mobile App and robots. Rise of the machines.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to implement pagination in MongoDB

```
  // Pagination
  const page = parseInt(req.query.page, 10) || 1;
  const limit = parseInt(req.query.limit, 10) || 25;
  const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
  const endIndex = page * limit;
  query = query.skip(startIndex).limit(limit);
```

Comment: This approach has it's drawbacks. It will have to skip the first n elements, meaning it will have to read the first n elements which will decrease the performance