# How can $facet improve $lookup performance

Tags: node.js, mongodb, join, mongoose, aggregation-framework

### Issue

I recently attended a tech meetup and showed some of my code to a much more experienced developer. He commented that I would run into issues with my pipeline due to `$lookup` and that I should consider using `$facet` to fix this.

I don't remember what issue he said I would run into nor how `$facet` could help fix it. I think it has something to do with the 16mb document limit but this can be resolved by using `$unwind` after `$lookup`.

### My code (Node.js)

I have a collection of `Post` documents. Some posts are *parent posts*, and other posts are *comments*. A post that is a comment is identified by the fact that its `parent` property is NOT `null`.

My goal is to return an array of the most recent parent posts and attach to each one, an int property that is the number of comments it has.

Here is my `Post` mongoose schema

```
const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    body: { type: String, required: true, trim: true },
    category: { type: String, required: true, trim: true, lowercase: true },
    timestamp: { type: Date, required: true, default: Date.now },
    parent: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Post', default: null },
});
```

Here is my pipeline

```
const pipeline = [
    { $match: { category: query.category } },
    { $sort: { timestamp: -1 } },
    { $skip: (query.page - 1) * query.count },
    { $limit: query.count },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'posts',
            localField: '_id',
            foreignField: 'parent',
            as: 'comments',
        },
    },
    {
        $addFields: {
            comments: { $size: '$comments' },
            id: '$_id',
        },
    },
    { $project: { _id: 0, __v: 0 } },
];
```

Comment: what result you expect? and also post some collection sample as well

Comment: `$facet` would not apply here. What I "presume" they would have been talking about was by "running the query separately" to "count comments". However what "they missed" was the fact that the "comments" are **related**, and in fact in a "different collection". So `$facet` cannot run on different collections. Running "separate queries" would be your better option for "performance". There are other options depending on your MongoDB version as to avoid BSON size problems.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In short, It cannot. But if anyone told you this then it deserves and explanation to clear up why such a concept is incorrect.

## Why NOT $facet

As commented, [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) cannot do anything for you here and was likely a miscommunication about what your query is meant to be doing. If anything, the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) pipeline stage would cause more problems with the BSON Limit due to the plain fact that the only output of the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) pipeline stage is a **"single document"**, which means that unless you are actually using it for the intended purpose of "summary results" then you will almost certainly breach this limit in real world conditions.

The biggest reason why it simply does not apply is because your [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) source is pulling in data from a different collection. The [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage only applies to the "same collection", so you cannot have output from one collection in one "facet" and another collection in a different facet. There can only be "pipelines" defined for the same collection on which the `.aggregate()` is being performed.

## $lookup is STILL what you want

The point of BSON Size limit however is perfectly valid, since the main failing in your current aggregation pipeline is using the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator on the returned array. The "array" is actually the problem here, since "unbound" this has the *"potential"* to pull in documents from the related collection that actually causes the parent document containing this array in output to exceed the BSON limit.

So there are two basic approaches to this which you can use in order to simply obtain the "size" without actually needing to create an array of the "whole" related documents.

### MongoDB 3.6 and greater

Here you would use [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) with the "sub-pipeline" expression syntax introduced in this version to simply return the "reduced count" without actually returning any documents:

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "category": query.category } },
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1 } },
    { "$skip": (query.page - 1) * query.count },
    { "$limit": query.count },
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "posts",
      "let": { "id": "$_id" },
      "pipeline": [
        { "$match": {
          "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$$id", "$parent" ] }
        }},
        { "$count": "count" }
      ],
      "as": "comments",
    }},
    { $addFields: {
        "comments": { 
          "$ifNull": [ { "$arrayElemAt": ["$comments.count", 0] }, 0 ]
        },
        "id": "$_id"
    }}
];
```

Very simply put the new "sub-pipeline" returns in the target "array" ( which is always an array ) **only** the output of the pipeline expression. Here not only do we [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) on the local and foreign key values ( which is actually what the other [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) form now does internally ), but we continue the pipeline using the [`$count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) stage, which is again actually a synonym for:

```
{ "$group": { "_id": null, "count": { "$sum": 1 } } },
{ "$project": { "_id": 0, "count": 1 } }
```

Point being that you only ever receive "one" document at most in the array response, which we can then easily transform into a singular value via [`$arrayElemAt`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/arrayElemAt/) and using [`$ifNull`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/) in case there were no matches in the foreign collection to obtain the count of `0`

### Earlier Versions

For earlier versions than MongoDB 3.6 the general idea is [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) directly after the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). This actually has a special action which is described under [**$lookup + $unwind Coalescence**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/#lookup-unwind-coalescence) in the wider manual section on [Aggregation Pipeline Optimization](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/aggregation-pipeline-optimization/). Personally I view these more as "hinderance" than "optimizations" as you really should be able to "express what you mean" instead of something doing things for you "behind you back". But the basics go like this:

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "category": query.category } },
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1 } },
    { "$skip": (query.page - 1) * query.count },
    { "$limit": query.count },
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "posts",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "parent",
      "as": "comments"
    }},
    { "$unwind": "$comments" },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "otherField": { "$first": "$otherField" },
      "comments": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
];
```

The important part here is what actually happens to both the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stages, as can be viewed using [`explain()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.explain/) to view the parsed pipeline as actually expressed by the server:

```
        {
            "$lookup" : {
                "from" : "posts",
                "as" : "comments",
                "localField" : "_id",
                "foreignField" : "parent",
                "unwinding" : {
                        "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays" : false
                }
            }
        }
```

That `unwinding` essentially gets "rolled into" the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) and the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) itself "disappears". This is because the combination gets translated in this "special way" which actually results in the "unwound" results of the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) instead of targeting an array. This is basically done so that if an "array" never actually gets created, then the BSON Limit can never be breached.

The rest is of course pretty simple in that you just use [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) in order to "group back" to the original document. You can use [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) as the accumulator in order to keep any fields of the document you want in the response and simply [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) to count the foreign data returned.

Since this is mongoose, I have already outlined a process for "automating" building all the fields to include with [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) as part of my answer on [Querying after populate in Mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44688386/2313887) which shows how to examine the "schema" in order to obtain that information.

Another "wrinkle" to this is the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) negates the "LEFT JOIN" inherent to [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) since where there is no matches to the parent content then that "parent document" is removed from results. I'm not quite certain on this as of writing ( and should look it up later ), but the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` option did have a restriction in that it could not apply in this form of "Coalescence", however this is not the case from at least MongoDB 3.6:

```
const pipeline = [
    { "$match": { "category": query.category } },
    { "$sort": { "timestamp": -1 } },
    { "$skip": (query.page - 1) * query.count },
    { "$limit": query.count },
    { "$lookup": {
      "from": "posts",
      "localField": "_id",
      "foreignField": "parent",
      "as": "comments"
    }},
    { "$unwind": { "path": "$comments", "preserveNullAndEmptyArrays": true } },
    { "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "otherField": { "$first": "$otherField" },
      "comments": {
        "$sum": {
          "$cond": {
            "if": { "$eq": [ "$comments", null ]  },
            "then": 0,
            "else": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }}
];
```

Since I cannot actually confirm that works properly in anything other than MongoDB 3.6, then it's kind of pointless since with the newer version you should do the different form of [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) anyway. I know that there was at least an initial problem with MongoDB 3.2 in that the `preserveNullAndEmptyArrays` cancelled out the "Coalescence" and hence the [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) still returned output as an "array", and only **after** that stage was the array "unwound". Which defeats the purpose of doing this to avoid the BSON limit.

---

## Do it in Code

All of that said, ultimately you are just looking for "counts" to be added to your results for the "related" comments. As long as you are not pulling in pages with "hundreds of items" then your [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) condition should keep this at a reasonable result to simply fire off [`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count) queries to obtain the matching document counts on each key without *"too much"* overhead to make it unreasonable:

```
// Get documents
let posts = await Post.find({ "category": query.category })
    .sort({ "timestamp": -1 })
    .skip((query.page - 1) * query.count)
    .limit(query.count)
    .lean().exec();

// Map counts to each document
posts = (await Promise.all(
  posts.map(post => Comment.count({ "parent": post._id }) )
)).map((comments,i) => ({ ...posts[i], comments }) );
```

The "trade-off" here is that whilst run "parallel" execution of all these [`count()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#count_count) queries means additional requests to the server, the overhead of each query in itself is actually really low. Obtaining the "cursor count" of the query result is a lot more efficient than using something like the [`$count`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/count/) aggregation pipeline stage shown above.

That puts a load on the database connections when executing, but it does not have the same "processing load" and of course you're only ever looking at "counts" and no documents are returned over the wire or even "fetched" from the collection in processing the cursor results.

So that last is basically an "optimize" on the mongoose `populate()` process, where we don't actually ask for the "documents" and simply get a count for each query. Technically `populate()` would use "one" query here with `$in` for all the documents in the prior result. But that won't work here because you want the total per "parent", which is essentially an aggregation in a single query and response. Hence why the "multiple-requests" are issued here.

## Summary

So in order to avoid the [BSON Limit](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#bson-documents) Problems, what you are really looking for is any of those techniques which avoids returning the "array" of related documents from your [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) pipeline stage which is used to "join", by either obtaining the "reduced data" or by a "cursor count" technique.

There is a bit more "depth" on the BSON Size Limit and handling at:

[Aggregate $lookup Total size of documents in matching pipeline exceeds maximum document size](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45724785/2313887) on this very site. Note that the same techniques demonstrated there to cause an error can also apply to the [`$facet`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/) stage as well since the 16MB limitation is a constant for anything which is a "document". And just about *"everything"* in MongoDB is a BSON Document, so working within the limits is extremely important.

> **NOTE**: Purely from a "performance" perspective the biggest problem outside of the potential BSON Size Limit breach inherent in your current query is actually the [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) processing. If what you are actually implementing is more of a "Load more results..." type of functionality, then something like [Implementing pagination in mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28105009/implementing-pagination-in-mongodb) where you would use a "range" to start the next "page" selection by excluding previous results is a lot more performance oriented than [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/).
>
> Paging with [`$skip`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/skip/) and [`$limit`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/limit/) should only be used where you really have no other option. Being on "numbered paging" where you can jump to any numbered page. And even then, it's still far better to instead "cache" results into pre-defined sets.
>
> But that really is a "whole other question" than the essential question here about the BSON Size Limit.

Comment: Thank you. Really well explained and extensive.
If you don't mind me asking,

If a document were to have  {**some absurd number**} comments, wouldn't using `$group` lead to the 100mb pipeline limit. I know I can enable using the disk to avoid this, I just want to confirm my suspicions. 
-------------------------- Also, you state that multiple count cursor queries may be faster than using `$count` in aggregation. Are you referring to your usage of `$count` in the **v3.6+** example?

Comment: @ThiagoP There's lots of links to the documentation throughout the answer and "any" operator used has a link back to it's documentation. There is always an "in memory limit" on all aggregation operations. 10% or 100MB which ever is greater before processes "need" to go to disk, but you typically need not be concerned because that just happens mostly without you needing to know. The greater concern as everything here addresses is the 16MB BSON Document size limit. This is a real problem from which your original referral comes from using `$size` on an array produced by `$lookup`.

Comment: also, keep in mind facet cannot use indexes so if you are working with large number of documents there is a good chance you run into slow queries and memory limitations. https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/facet/#index-use