# Paginate Mongoose / MongoDB query: sort by two fields starting from a point

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to sort a collection by the `rating` field and the `_id` field, both descending `{ $sort: { rating:-1 }, { _id:-1 } }`. Since I'm using `$limit` I want to be able to do another request to get the following objects. I tried doing it with a `$match` like this `{ rating: {$lte: lastRating}, _id : { $lt: lastID} }`, where `lastRating` and `lastID` are the previous values of the last item in the last returned array But that doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are describing is called **pagination**.

How to implement this pattern is already described in depth by many others (like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28105442/11641932)). *leaving this here for others*

The reason your query does not return any documents on the next page, however, is probably simple because the tiebreaker is implemented incorrectly (I am assuming you are using the `_id` as tiebreaker).

It should look similar to this:

```js
// page 1
collection
  .find({})
  .sort({ rating: -1, _id: -1 })
  .limit(limit)
  .toArray();
```

```js
// page n
collection
  .find({
    $and: [
      { ...any actual query here },
      // this is the pagination query
      {
        $or: [
          { rating: { $lt: lastRating } },
          {
            rating: lastRating,
            _id: { $lt: ObjectId(lastID) } 
        ]
    ]
  })
  .sort({ rating: -1, _id: -1 })
  .limit(limit)
  .toArray();
```

Comment: thank you for this! The $or is clever for handling the tie-break situation. Exactly what I needed.